# Mixed-language dictionaries for Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, language

I am frequently writing Emails, where German and English parts are mixed **within a single email**. Is it possible to get Spell-Checking that doesn't require manually switching languages all the time?

Partial solutions exist; Natively, Thunderbird supports only a single dictionary at a time; The extension [Automatic Dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/automatic-dictionary-switching/?src=superuser.com) aims to make switching easier, but assumes that for any given contact only ever a single language will be used, and it can't handle multiple languages in a single Email. The extension [Multilingual Dictionary](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/multilingual-dictionary/?src=superuser.com) would be a solution, if it supported other combinations than Greek+English.

My guess for a solution would be to create a combined English+German dictionary, but I could only find solutions related to the "personal dictionary", which is a different thing (more about adding unusual words, like names, to reduce the false-positives, than about adding a whole language).

Comment: I also looking for solution of this problem. Did you find it by any chance?

Comment: @S1awek I once merged German and English dictionaries with a script (since such a merged dictionary does not cover rules for compound words and grammatical variations of words). Can't find my old post anymore though, and it after all didn't work too reliably. Beyond that? No, sadly. Only Google Chrome does this well out of the box. At work I have just gotten used to using the "Context menu" key to quickly toggle languages.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. I guess we'll have live with it.